# How do I find the file location of a draw.io file I have created?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have been trying multiple different approaches for how to share and collaborate on draw.io files using teams as a storage mechanism.

This works to a point but is hugely un-intuitive. I have recently discovered the 'Link' functionality in the web app which is great as it launches the webapp and links directly to the file I have created (provided the use has permissions).

Only issue I have now is  I cannot find from the Draw.IO user interface where the source file is in Sharepoint Teams - - there seems to no File Property that states "the source file is here: https://teams.sharepoint.com/library/filenmame.drawio".

I have multiple copies of files all over the place now (as a result of experimenting with sharing) and I cant find anywhere to tell me "here is your file".

Comment: Only workaround so far. Modify the diagram. Look all files in folder to see which one has recent modification time.